# How to check if Gmail is turn on for a user in G Suite?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

Scenario 1:
According to this article: [Remove a G Suite service](https://support.google.com/a/answer/45691): An administrator can uninstall Gmail for all users.

Scenario 2:
According to this article: [Turn Gmail on or off for a group of users](https://support.google.com/a/answer/57919): An administrator can put a user in an organization unit and turn on/off Gmail for the organization.

My question is: how to check if Gmail is turned on/off for a user in G Suite by Google API? (both Scenario 1 & Scenario 2)

I know that if I send API `https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels` by the user in Scenario 2, I'll get a response like

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "failedPrecondition",
                "message": "Mail service not enabled"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Mail service not enabled"
    }
}
```

But I'm afraid that this response is not specific enough and the message "Mail service not enabled" may vary as time goes by.

Comment: To people getting here from Google: The "Mail service not enabled" error can appear when your 14 day G Suite trial expires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Directory API, Users resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource), `isMailboxSetup` can be used for checking the mail service

> Indicates if the user's Google mailbox is created. This property is
>   only applicable if the user has been assigned a Gmail license.

My test result:

- a normal user's `isMailboxSetup` with Gmail service eanbled: `true`
- a suspended user's `isMailboxSetup`: `true`
- the user's `isMailboxSetup` in scenario 1 (uninstall Gmail for all users): `false`
- the user's `isMailboxSetup` in scenario 2 (turn off Gmail for the organization): `false`